# How to change a custom tab bar button state after button tap from another tab

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a custom tab bar in my app. I am using a raised custom button for the middle of the tab bar. This custom middle button should change to a selected state after the user makes a button tap from the first tab.

The button's action on the first tab is:

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

I am using my own Tabbar Controller class so I am able to draw the custom button in the middle. I have the button changing states when it is selected manually, but I need it to change states when the button tap occurs from the first tab and sets the selected index to the middle tabbar button.

Let me know if I can give more information. Thanks for putting up with a newb!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by casting self.tabBarController to my custom tabBarController:

```
customTabBarController *tabBarController = (customTabBarController *)self.tabBarController;
```

Then to reference the button and set selected I simply did:

```
[tabBarController.button setSelected:YES];
```

Answer (score -1):

I understand ur problem regarding custom tab bar and you can customize ur tab bar.

Here is some sample codes and ideas for this. Check this link [Custom Tab Bar customize](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tabbar)

I hope it helps u.